# XMLEncoder does not encode zero values

Tags: java, xmlencoder

I'm encoding a short integer with value 0 and XMLEncoder does not encode it.

How can I force it?

Comment: What do mean by a short integer, what primitive type are you using?

Comment: like so: private short order;

Comment: I switched to another library: XStream (http://xstream.codehaus.org/)

Much simpler and it works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I switched to another library: XStream (http://x-stream.github.io/)

Much simpler and it works.

Comment: Don't anwer your own question please, put a comment under it.

Answer (score 0):

XMLEncoder does not encode *default* values. It saves space. It works.

Comment: It works sometimes. Unfortunately unless the semantics are well defined (e.g. a correctly used XSD -- perhaps with xsl:nil -- or documentation) it might leave someone with some "bad data". A missing attribute is different than an attribute with a default value.

Comment: I'm referring to values that are defaulted in the Java code, not the XSD. Not sure what XSD's have to do with XMLEncoder actually, they all share the same one.